# Show that for $p>1,$ $\mathbb{E}[Y^p] \leq \big(\frac{p}{p-1}\big)^p\mathbb{E}[X^p]$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, holder-inequality

Let $X$ and $Y$ be non-negative r.v. defined on the same probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ such that

$$\mathbb{P}(Y>y)\leq\frac1y \int_{Y\geq y}^{} X d\mathbb{P} $$

Show that for $p>1$,

$$\mathbb{E}[Y^p]\leq\Big(\frac{p}{p-1}\Big)^p \mathbb{E}[X^p]$$

Suggestion:

Recall that for a non-negative random variable $X$,

$$||X||_p^p=\mathbb{E}[X^p]=\int_{0}^{\infty}px^{p-1}\mathbb{P}(X>x)$$

and Holder's inequality states that for $p,q$ such that $\frac1p + \frac1q = 1$,

$$\mathbb{E}[ZW]\leq||Z||_p||W||_q=\mathbb{E}[Z^p]^{1/p}\mathbb{E}[W^q]^{1/q}$$

Comment: Given that the problem has two hints, I assume it is a homework problem?  What progress have you had at applying them?

Comment: Also this is very standard and a proof can be found in almost any book that deals with martingale theory.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy can you tell me where to find such proof?

Comment: One such place is Doob's Stochastic Processes. Most likely it is there in Chung's book also but I don't have the book with me at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Big hints:

- Start with $E[Y^p]$ and use the given formula which will have a $P(Y > y)$ in the integrand.
- Use the given inequality to bound $P(Y > y)$ in the integrand.
- Exchange the order of integration and evaluate the inner integral.
- Use Hölder's inequality on the remaining integral.

---

Response to comment:

$$\int_0^\infty p y^{p-2} \int_\Omega X 1_{Y \ge y} \,dP \, dy
= p \int_\Omega X \int_0^Y y^{p-2}  \, dy \, dP$$

Comment: Yeah, the first two steps were more or less obvious... The problem is the third one, because I don't see how exchanging the order of integration gets me anywhere.

Comment: @Babado "Obviousness" is relative; others might say the entire exercise is "obvious." When posting questions it is better to include what you've tried and where you are stuck, so that people can help you more directly. After exchanging the order of integration, the inner integral will be of the form $\int_0^Y \cdots \, dy$ which can be evaluated directly.

Comment: Can you explicitly say which integral do one get and what you need to do? That's the part where I'm stuck...

Comment: @Babado See my edit

Comment: Ok, I've seen it... And then you aplly Holders inequality to $Z=X$ and $W=Y^{p-1}$? Even if you do, I don't know how you get the inequality on the right.

Comment: @Babado By applying Hölder you get $$\mathsf E(Y^p)\le \frac{p}{p-1}\|X\|_p \|Y^{p-1}\|_{\frac{p}{p-1}}$$ Now expand this using $$\|Z\|_q=\mathsf E(Z^q)^\frac1q$$ for a $q$-integrable rv. $Z$ and number $q$ and try to conclude the original inequality

Comment: A further hint: Divide both sides of the inequality by some power of $$\mathsf E(Y^p)$$

Comment: Ok I finally got it. Thanks for all the help